# Sort alphabetically and get only first of every letter of the alphabet

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL table called `names` with a column names `name`.

This column has the following values:

```
Beacher
Ackley
Addison
Caldwell
Cameron
Alcott
Carling
Beardsley
Beldon
```

I want to get, alphabetically sorted, the value of every first letter.

Alphabetically sorted the list above is like this:

```
Ackley
Addison
Alcott
Beacher
Beardsley
Beldon
Caldwell
Cameron
Carling
```

The first value starting with `A` is `Ackley`, the first value starting with `B` is `Beacher` …

So I want the following output:

```
Ackley
Beacher
Caldwell
```

Is this even possible with a single SQL query? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers that use the `row_number()` window function require that you have MySQL 8.0.

Here's a solution that should work on MySQL 5.x.

```
select left(name, 1) as c, min(name) from names group by c;
+------+-----------+
| c    | min(name) |
+------+-----------+
| A    | Ackley    |
| B    | Beacher   |
| C    | Caldwell  |
+------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `row_number`:

```
select nombre
from (
  select 
    row_number() over (partition by left(nombre, 1) order by nombre asc) as rn,
    nombre
  from names
  ) n
where rn = 1
```

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z-cYI22O)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. This throws an error. I tried the following: `select name from (select row_number() over (partition by left(name, 1) order by name asc) as rn, name from names) n where rn = 1`

Comment: Do I need to add the `with data as` stuff in the query? Because my data is in the MySQL database already.

Comment: @David no, it's just for the example

Comment: This doesn't work with MySQL 5.7, does it?

Comment: No... it works since 8.0 ahead. You didn't mention your mysql version, it's quite old btw

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to mention that. Answer of BillKarwin is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
with main as (
select 
*, 
row_number() over(partition by left(column,1) order by column) as rank_
)
select column where rank_ = 1
```

Steps:

- `column` =  your actual column name
- First we are creating a `CTE` that does two things. It creates a rank using the windows function `row_number()`. This rank is build using the following logic: Pick the column's first letter i.e the use of `LEFT()` function(1 specifies the placement i.e the first letter in our case). This will eventually tell SQL to pick every word's first letter. The second functionality is the `ORDER BY` within the window function.
- The `ORDER BY` orders all the words based on the A-Z i.e Ascending order by default. If you use `DESC` it will return the last word for the same starting character.
- Connecting both logics, what we get is the rank based on the ascending order of each word and the first character. [All the first words starting with each alphabet in a given data set]
- In the final select we just filter the `rank_ = 1` in the where clause
- If you want the last word you can just use `order by column DESC`

IF windows function is not supported you can use the following solution, the logic remains almost the same:

```
with main as (
select
column,
left(column,1) as first_letter_per_word
from [table_name]
)

select
first_letter_per_word,
min(column) as word
from main 
group by 1  -- by default it is ASC
```

Comment: This doesn't work with MySQL 5.7, does it?

Comment: @David what code are you running can you share ?

Comment: @David can you check if the new solution works ? i have changed it

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I'm using MySQL 5.7. Answer of BillKarwin is working.

Comment: @David does the second solution above works ?

Comment: Answer of BillKarwin is working. Or are you still interested if yours is working? Is there a difference?

Comment: i believe they are the same but you can check